# How we can change or remove owner logo from Embed code of video/ info graphic?

Tags: html, embed

Whenever I copy a code from any infographic provider ( free services ) they add their logo in the infographic, so is there any option any code to remove their logo from embed code?

I have already tried some features but without success.

Answer (score 1):

The logo can be removed easily using ffmpeg, by using its delogo filter. All you need to supply is the co-ordinates and dimensions of the logo present on the video.

Example for the filter syntax:

```
ffmpeg -i your_video_url -f "delogo=x=0:y=0:w=100:h=77:band=10" -r outup_file_url
```

Find the complete filter info [here](https://libav.org/documentation/libavfilter.html#delogo).

Answer (score 0):

simple answer: no. they put their lgoo there as their copyright to give them credit.

Comment: yes you are right... but there should be any way to remove there logo or name ???

Comment: your asking to violate someones copyright. they put that logo there, because its their copyright.